# Openstack: Increase Hypervisor resources

Tags: virtualization, cloud, openstack

Is there any way to increase resources of the hypervisor on OpenStack, e.g: VCPU, memory or Number of the volumes?

I can use the following command to see them:

```
openstack hypervisor stats show
```

But I can't find the configuration file. I am not sure if it is possible to change them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available resources are limited by the compute (and storage) hardware, but you can overcommit CPU, RAM and disk, see the [docs](https://docs.openstack.org/arch-design/design-compute/design-compute-overcommit.html) for more information. For example, the default CPU overallocation ratio is 1:16, so one physical CPU results in 16 virtual CPUs. The respective config value is [cpu_allocation_ratio](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/zed/configuration/config.html#DEFAULT.cpu_allocation_ratio) in nova.conf. But be aware that overcommitting can lead to performance degredation and is highly depending on your workload. As for the volumes, you can always [resize](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/zed/cli/cli-manage-volumes.html) (increase) volumes if the free space in your storage back end allows it.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the resources of the **hypervisor** you need to add additional hardware.

- CPU: replace the CPU with one that has more cores
- RAM: add/replace memory modules
- storage: add/replace hard disks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase resource is to either upgrade the `compute-node` itself by putting  more hardware resources in server (Ram , second Cpu , etc) or

add additional `compute-node` to nova.